# Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket when transposing

Tags: matlab, transpose, parentheses, brackets

I got this error when I use MATLAB R2014a.

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
A'(:) = [2 2 2 3 3 3];
```

But it works when I separate it into two steps:

```
B = A';
B(:) = [2 2 2 3 3 3];
```

Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: `A'(:)` is invalid Matlab syntax. Try `A(:).'` instead. (Use `.'` rather than `'` for matrix transpose rather than conjugate transpose). You can't use bracket indexing after anything except the variable name.

Comment: @David please post that as an answer

Comment: @David But `A(:).'` is not the same as what `A.'(:)` would do. You could use `A = reshape([2 2 2 3 3 3], size(A,2), size(A,1));`

Answer (score 2):

In Matlab, you can't do `A'(:)`, because the indexing has to appear first. Instead, do `A(:)'` (or use `reshape` to give better control: `reshape(A,1,[])` (I think!)).

You can do some strange things, like this: `A{2}(:)` or `A.matrix(1)` because they are just indexing, but you can't do things like this: `sum(A)(:)` or `A^2(:)`.

One a more technical note, you should do `A(:).'`, because `'` does the conjugate transpose, as opposed to `.'`, which does a regular matrix transpose. Of course in most cases they are the same, but it's best to do the right thing and you will never get tripped up by a (very) weird error!

Comment: You could mention the function `transpose` as the equivalent of `.'`

Comment: That's a good point, and makes everything much more clear @Matt.